# Transferir conteudo de uma Div para outra

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Ola eu preciso criar uma função que seja capaz de movimentar o conteudo de uma div para outra, por exemplo

```html
            <li class="itens-interface" id="to-do">
                <div class="topo-interface">
                    <h2 class="font-l">Para fazer</h2>
                </div>
                <div class='body-list' id="to-do-body">
                       <div class="tarefas" id="0">
                            <textarea class="titulo-ef" readonly="readonly">asdasd</textarea>
                            <textarea class="conteudo-ef" readonly="readonly">sadasd</textarea>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="itens-interface" id="in-p">
                <div class="topo-interface">
                    <h2 class="font-l">Em progresso</h2>
                </div>
                <div class='body-list' id="in-p-body">
                </div>
            </li>
```

eu preciso mover a div com a class "tarefas" de dentro da "to-do-body" para a "in-p-body".
E alem disso, isso precisa ocorrer clicando em cima do titulo da tarefa que seria a textarea "titulo-ef".

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Atualmente to com o problema de que eu tenho 4 objetos (To-do,in-p,rmk,complete) que são os estados das tarefas, e eu preciso encontrar uma forma de na função de transferir o conteudo das div tarefas de uma coluna para outra eu consiga identifcar qual é o estado dessa tarefa, se ela esta na coluna To Do ou In Progress, pra mim saber qual tratamento dar a ela, estava pensando em utilizar o Parents() do jQuery mas n sei se ele se aplica a esse caso.

Comment: Fazendo alguns testes aqui utilizando o closest() eu consigo pelo console identificar se é ou não o parent que eu preciso, porem não sei como poderia fazer essa identificação dentro do codigo

Comment: Vamos ver se consegui compreender, você quer que ao clicar no textarea titulo-ef, todo o conteúdo da div tarefas (ou seja, a div e seus dois textareas) desapareça da div to-do-body e vá parar na div in-p-body, é isso?

Comment: exato, o conteudo tem que ser deletado de uma coluna e passado para a outra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luan,

Você pode criar um `onclick` no textarea, no caso o *titulo-ef*:

```
<textarea onclick"moveDiv(this)" class="titulo-ef" readonly="readonly">asdasd</textarea>
```

Declarar a função `moveDiv`, recebendo o `this` (textArea), assim já tendo acesso ao textarea e seu `parent`:

```
function moveDiv(textArea) {
  //Pego a div de destino
  let divEmPrograsso = document.getElementById("in-p-body");

  //Faço o append de todo o conteúdo do parent do textArea, que no caso é a div <div class="tarefas" id="0">
  divEmPrograsso.appendChild(textArea.parentElement);
  //Removo o evento de click, essa linha não terá efeito, mas pode ser útil conforme suas implementações
  textArea.removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

Com isso eu já consigo fazer toda da mudança do conteúdo de uma DIV para outra.

---

Veja um exemplo prático:

```js
function moveDiv(textArea) {
  let divEmPrograsso = document.getElementById("in-p-body");
  divEmPrograsso.appendChild(textArea.parentElement);
  textArea.removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

```html
<li class="itens-interface" id="to-do">
  <div class="topo-interface">
    <h2 class="font-l">Para fazer</h2>
  </div>

  <div class='body-list' id="to-do-body">
    <div class="tarefas" id="0">
      <textarea onclick="moveDiv(this)" class="titulo-ef" readonly="readonly">asdasd</textarea>
      <textarea id="conteudo-ef" class="conteudo-ef" readonly="readonly">sadasd</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="itens-interface" id="in-p">
  <div class="topo-interface">
    <h2 class="font-l">Em progresso</h2>
  </div>

  <div class='body-list' id="in-p-body">
  </div>
</li>
```